# Mongodb Spark SQL ConfigException - Missing configuration for: database

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mongo-connector

I am using mongo spark connector 10.1.1 (spark v2.13) and am attempting to read a collection's contents into a dataset for processing.
The spark session is configured as below:

```
//Build Spark session
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("ExampleApp")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/test_db")
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/test_db")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection", "ExampleCollection")
    .getOrCreate();
```

And I am then attempting to load the contents into a dataset object:

```
//Load data and infer schema
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().format("mongodb").load();
```

This triggers the stack trace below:

```
com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.exceptions.ConfigException: Missing configuration for: database
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.assertions.Assertions.validateConfig(Assertions.java:69) ~[mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.config.AbstractMongoConfig.getDatabaseName(AbstractMongoConfig.java:111) ~[mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.config.ReadConfig.getDatabaseName(ReadConfig.java:45) ~[mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.config.AbstractMongoConfig.withCollection(AbstractMongoConfig.java:175) ~[mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.config.ReadConfig.withCollection(ReadConfig.java:45) ~[mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.InferSchema.inferSchema(InferSchema.java:82) ~[mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.MongoTableProvider.inferSchema(MongoTableProvider.java:62) ~[mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:90) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.loadV2Source(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:140) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:209) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:207) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
```

suggesting there is an issue with the configuration for the spark session. I have attempted to add the database name as a separate property: "spark.mongodb.input.database", and remove from the uris but the exact same error is thrown.
All other threads on this topic refer to loading using the `MongoSpark` class, but this appears to be deprecated for this version of the connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change parameter names.

For reading:

```
sparkSession.format("mongodb")
  .option("spark.mongodb.read.database", databaseName)
  .option("spark.mongodb.read.collection", collectionName)
  .option("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", s"mongodb://$userName:$password@$host:$port")
```

and for writing:

```
 sparkSession.format("mongodb")
  .option("spark.mongodb.write.database", databaseName)
  .option("spark.mongodb.write.collection", collectionName)
  .option("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", s"mongodb://$userName:$password@$host:$port")
```

Comment: You are correct  - I was still reviewing documentation from an older version